# Azure Application Insights Status Monitor error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005)

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I hope this question is not asked many times before. First I searched the contributions but did not find the answer.

I have very first experiences with Application Insights Status Monitor.
It works fine on a web server where AI Status Monitor is installed and connected to my Azure Subscription.
The monitored IIS applications are present within the Azure Management Portal and it is possible to analyze data.
I am happy with it.

But, on an other web server it does not work.
As an administrator I installed the AI Status Monitor. I use the latest version, downloaded yesterday 2017-06-22.
When I run it, it starts as expected.
But when I try connecting to my Azure Subscription by "Sign in" the enclosed error message occurs.

Both machines are running Windows Server 2012 Standard with IIS.

Would be great if at least one of you can give advice on how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Andi

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the 
COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the 
following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, 
Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, 
StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.Core.Azure.AzureConnector.Login()
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.UI.ActionPanel.ActionPanel.PerformLogInWithProgress()
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.DoUserInitiatedNavigation(Object sender)
   at System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent 
newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 
timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr 
wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr 
lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 
numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, 
Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, 
Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Agent.StatusMonitor.App.Main()
```

Answer (score 1):

CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the error message is a CLSID of Internet Explorer that's trying to be launched by Status Monitor for user authentication.

So mostly probably you have a problems with IE installation on that box - check that you have it correctly installed and re-install if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your help and with help of my IT we got it done. It was a problem with IE settings. It works for me. Thanks again.